# How to save asp.net textbox values with one button click and use that data for another button click?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a table with a row that allows the user to insert data into two textboxes, and a asp.net button called insert to bind that row to the gridview.  Within the table I have a gridview which shows all the data populated form SQL Server, and any inserted rows which could be one, or many insertions based on button clicks.   Then I have a submit button to submit the changes to SQL SERVER DB.

For example, the user enters some data into 2 textboxes then hits the insert button which just inserts that row into the gridview.  The user can either add more rows, or hit the submit button.  If the user hits the submit button, a stored procedure happens based on how many rows have been inserted.

I am not understanding how to send data from one button event to another button event using C# back-end ASP.NET front-end?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Question here are more likely to be answered if you post what you have tried. we can suggest solution to the actual problem you are facing with your code efforts.

Comment: I don't have any code yet.  I am just thinking of what route to take to solve this problem.  Should I go server side when the button clicks to insert a row, or should I go client-side to insert a new row?

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of is after first insert store the IDENT_current and when you click on submit button include the where clause in store procedure where the given id value is greater than IDENT_Current that way all the effects mentioned in stored procedure will take place on inserted data.